# NSArray with week days

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a question, In my app I have an NSMutableArray which contains name with days of the week, sometimes is just Sunday and Saturday, sometimes is just Monday or Tuesday, my question is: I want that when my array will contain just entry like this: Sunday and Saturday to save a NSString with name @"Weekends", or  when will contain Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday to save a  NSString with name @"Weekdays", and of course when will be just a day to have an NString with initials in this format "Mon, Tue, etc ". Thanks!!!

Comment: Are those the only two options? Can it contain Friday and Saturday? Or Sunday and Monday?

Comment: I would create class `Week` with 7 bool properties: Mon, Tue, etc. And with readonly property `description`, that returns what you need.

Comment: No, will be more options, like you said Friday and Saturday will be NSString in format @"Fri Sat"; Sunday and Monday will be @"Mon Sun"; and so on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this method to rationalize an array to "Weekdays" or "Weekend" if it contains the correct days.  Else it will leave the array intact.  It's easy to change to make it return a string instead, but I'll leave that to you.

```
- (NSArray *)rationalizeDaysOfWeek:(NSArray *)daysOfWeek
{
    if ([self array:daysOfWeek
          matchesArray:@[ @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday", @"Thursday", @"Friday"]]) {
        return @[ @"Weekdays" ];
    }
    if ([self array:daysOfWeek
        matchesArray:@"[ @"Saturday", @"Sunday"]]) {
        return @[ @"Weekend" ];
    }
    return daysOfWeek;
}

- (BOOL)array:(NSArray *)array1 matchesArray:(NSArray *)array2
{
    if ([array1 count] != [array2 count])
        return NO;
    for (NSString *value in array1)
        if ([array2 indexOfObject:value] == NSNotFound)
            return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @DanPaschevici: Well?